# How to compare arraylist value and array value in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, size

```
int sizeOfTheShortestList = webresult.size();
    for (int i=0; i<sizeOfTheShortestList; i++) {
        if (webresult1.get(i).equals(dbresult[i]) )
        {
          System.out.println("Equals..: " + webresult1.get(i));
     }
 }
```

from above code i find errors please give solution to compare arraylist values and array values

Comment: ....try comparing their length as well, maybe throw in null-checks for good measure

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: the solution you are using is not good, time-consuming

Answer (score 2):

Take arraylist as 'al'.
Take array as 'a'.

now u need to compare 'al' and 'a'.

```
iterator it = new iterator(al);
int length = a.size();
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<length; i++)
{
    if(it.next()==a[i]);
    {
        count++;
    }
}
if(count == length)
{
    System.out.println("Both are equal");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Both are not equal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [`ArrayList#retailAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> Retains only the elements in this list that are contained in the
>   specified collection. In other words, removes from this list all of
>   its elements that are not contained in the specified collection.

```
webresult.retainAll(Arrays.asList(dbresult);
// Now webresult will only contain the values that were in webresult and are in dbresult
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
int sizeOfTheShortestList = Math.min(webresult.size(), webresult1.length);
        for (int i=0; i<sizeOfTheShortestList; i++) {
            if (webresult.get(i).equals(webresult1[i]) {
                System.out.println("Equals..: " + webresult.get(i));
            }
        }
```

I hope I understood your question in right way..otherwise please comment

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to compare the lengths of both webresult and dbresult, because if they are of different lengths you will get IndexOutOfBounds exception.
2. Is webresult.get(i) is of the same **type** as of dbresult[i]?
3. Implementation of equals, missing from question, should add that too, if not using default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ArrayList#toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) to convert your list to an array.

Then you can use [Arrays#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28boolean%5b%5d,%20boolean%5b%5d%29) to compare the two arrays.

The objects that you are comparing will have to override [Object#eqauls()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of errors you get.
Another solution would be to use the toArray() method on your arraylist and compare 2 arrays. But your code should work if the data structures have the same length, because you are comparing the elements from the array and arraylist, not the collections themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your arraylist is shorter than the array (otherwise you'd get an IndexOutOfBounds exception), you should make sure that the types of webresult.get(i) and dbresult[i] are the same. Also, ".equals()" only works for comparing objects (such as Strings), and not for primitives. So if webresult.get(i) and dbresult[i] are ints or chars, ".equals" will not work. You should use "==" instead.